# query needs to return all items from Result1 list which are not present in Result2

Tags: c#, list

```
public List<Model_Result> GetEsEmails { get; set; }
```

Hi:

My query needs to return all items from splitted1 list which EmailIDs are not present in GetEsEmails.

Please could you help with syntax.

```
public void SenDEmail(string esemails)
{
//splitting email string 
      var splitted1 = esmails.Emails.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Replace(";",""));

  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();


    var result1 = splitted1
          .Where(x => GetEsEmails.All(email => x != email.EmailAddress))
          .ToList();
```

}

Thank you,
urpalshu

Answer (score 1):

Linq. I love Linq? Don't you love Linq? Linq has `Except`. `Except` is fun.

```
var addressesToIgnore = GetEsEmails.Select(email => email.EmailAddress);
var results = splitted1.Except(addressesToIgnore );
```

Note the first line, which extracts just the `EmailAddress` property into an `IEnumerable`. Then the second line returns a new `IEnumerable` that contains only the members of `splitted1` that aren't in `addressesToIgnore`;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you might want to do it like this:
"I want those x strings from splitted1 for which it is not true that GetEsEmails contains any a elements for which a.Email equals to x"

```
    var result1 = splitted1
              .Where(x => !GetEsEmails.Any(a=>a.Email==x))
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong, there's nothing wrong with your linq either (I blindly believed that that's the thing which is bad and wrote the 1st thing that came into my mind). But it might be with your splitted1. Can a line contain a lone ; ? Because if your esmail string is something like I think of: "xx@xxx.xx;\nzzz@zzz.zz\n" then you might want to replace ;-s in your original string and not in your already split string array.